# Doctrine ORM order by annotations object fields

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, annotations

So its simple like this : I have the following code in some Entity

```
     /**
     * @var ServiceOffer
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ServiceOffer", mappedBy="serviceProvider")
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"service" = "desc"})
     */
    private $offers;
```

What i need is to do something like this

```
     /**
     * @var ServiceOffer
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ServiceOffer", mappedBy="serviceProvider")
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"service.points" = "desc"})
     */
    private $offers;
```

which is not working i don't want to do it through some function i wanted straight forward with annotations is there any way to do this ?

this is the points btw:

```
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="points", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $points;
```

Comment: 'points' is an attribute of ServiceOffer?

Comment: No its an attribute in Service Entity

Comment: I afraid that only can be done through a DQL query. Doctrine ORM doesn't support that yet :(

Comment: `ServiceProvider -> ServiceOffe -> Service -> points`. Like that?

Comment: yep what i am trying to do is to search for ServiceProviders and then sort there ServiceOffers throughout the service points :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. This is not possible. You should solve this creating a dql.

> The DQL Snippet in OrderBy is only allowed to consist of unqualified, unquoted field names and of an optional ASC/DESC positional statement. Multiple Fields are separated by a comma (,). **The referenced field names have to exist on the targetEntity class of the @ManyToMany or @OneToMany annotation**.

More in [doctrine2 documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-orderby).

**DQL Example**

```
SELECT provider, offer, service
  FROM \MyNamespace\Entity\ServiceProvider provider
  INNER JOIN provider.offers offer
  INNER JOIN offer.service service
WHERE 
  provider.id = 1
```

Notice, this code snippet `provider, offer, service` it's important to return here all entities or fields you will need so doctrine will load it for once, if it's possible. In other words, if you did'nt include any entity and call for it, doctrine will load it lazily.

Comment: and this will cause a heavy load cuz i might be searching over tons of records and to create a query for each record will end up in a huge number of queries ....

Comment: no. it isn't. The query is lighter than a simple `find` without the eager fetch mecanism. I will include a dql in a answer. It can be created to generate a single sql.

Comment: i accepted the part with the "This is not possible" as an answer but the problem is still there 

this is my query

$query->select("sp")
    ->from("CoreBundle:ServiceProvider","sp")
    ->andWhere("sp.city = :city_name")->setParameter("city_name",$cityName)
                ->orderBy("sp.points DESC , sp.name");

and even if i added the inner join or without 
i still need to do a query for each service provider 
which means i need to do at least a 1000 queries per search which is still alot

Comment: i still cant order the "offers from service provider by their own points"

Comment: i tried this one $query->select("sp")
    ->from("CoreBundle:ServiceProvider","sp")
    ->andWhere("sp.city = :city_name")->setParameter("city_name",$cityName)
                ->innerJoin("sp.offers","offer")
                ->innerJoin("offer.service","service","with","offer.service = service")
                ->orderBy("sp.points DESC , sp.name ASC , service.points");

but its not working

Comment: Points are in service. Aren't they? You are using from ServiceProvider ‛sp.points‛. I will update my answer, including the ‛order by‛.

Comment: i am posting a new question for this issue

Comment: but yes i have points in service and points in service provider

Comment: this is the question @Vinícius Fagundes  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41131139/mysql-sorting-with-doctrine