# MYSQL sorting with doctrine

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

as described in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41126279/doctrine-orm-order-by-annotations-object-fields) and as its answered with "Not possible"
 i opened a new question

so my problem goes like this :
I have a table (ServiceProvider Table)
each service provider have many offers (Offer table) with a OneToMany relation 
and each Offer have a master service (Service table) with a ManyToOne relation.
What i am trying to do is to get all the service providers and their offers in an order related to serviceProvider.points and then serviceProvider.name and each service provider's offers should be ordered by their points.
So for more clear view let's say i have the following

```
ServiceProvider
-------------------------------------------------
id      |        name     |    points    |offers|
-------------------------------------------------  
1       |        c        |      2       |1,2,3 |
-------------------------------------------------
2       |        b        |      1       |1,2   |
-------------------------------------------------
3       |        a        |      0       |1,3   |
-------------------------------------------------
ServiceOffer
-----------------------------------
id      |     name        |service|
-----------------------------------
1       |      a          |   1   |
-----------------------------------
2       |      b          |   1   |
-----------------------------------
3       |      c          |   2   |
-----------------------------------
Service
-----------------------------------
id      |    name    |    points  |
-----------------------------------
1       |      a     |      23    |
-----------------------------------
2       |      b     |      88    |
-----------------------------------
```

what i exactly need is a result like this

```
results
service_provider.name| offers.name  |
-------------------------------------
c                    |   b , a      |
-------------------------------------
b                    |   a , b      |
-------------------------------------
a                    |   b , a      |
-------------------------------------
```

this is the query i tried but it's not working

```
$query->select("sp")
            ->from("CoreBundle:ServiceProvider","sp")
            ->andWhere("sp.city = :city_name")->setParameter("city_name",$cityName)
            ->innerJoin("sp.offers","offer")
            ->innerJoin("offer.service","service","with","offer.service = service")
            ->orderBy("sp.points DESC , sp.name ASC , service.points");
```

needed fields

in serviceProvider

```
/**
* @var ServiceOffer
*
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ServiceOffer", mappedBy="serviceProvider")
*/
private $offers;
```

in service

```
/**
* @var integer
*
* @ORM\Column(name="points", type="integer", nullable=true)
*/
private $points;
```

in service offer

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Service", inversedBy="offer")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="service_id", referencedColumnName="id")
*
* @Serializer\Expose
* @Serializer\Groups({"service-offer", "order-entry"})
*
* @Assert\NotBlank(message="constraint.serviceOffer.service.not_blank")
*/
private $service;
```

Comment: Why offers is a list in ServiceProvider table?

Comment: because this is the DB model i have :/

Comment: Can you include your entities codes? I don't  think the map is correct.

Comment: yeah the mapping is kinda not perfect but i am dealing with almost a 50 tables which needs to be restructured at one point but no time for a huge project now even the entities are kinda huge :/
anyway i will add the needed fields from entities to the question

Comment: In order to map it as a  `ServiceProvider -> OneToMany <- ServiceOffer`. You should either create a intermediate table or include a foreign key in ServiceOffer (and of course, remove offers from ServiceProvider) it seems like a ManyToMany without a intermediate table.

Comment: Why don't you search by Offers instead of Providers? You're looking for offers and each offer would appear to give you a relationship to the provider?

Comment: Please, also include the `$serviceProvider` attribute from ServiceOffer, with its map.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simply enumerate `ORDER BY` directives to Doctrine. You may give a single `->orderBy()` method call, giving the field to use and direction (optional, `ASC` is default) as arguments, and further order fields must be add using the `addOrderBy` method. Your query should look like

```
$query->select("sp")
    ->from("CoreBundle:ServiceProvider","sp")
    ->andWhere("sp.city = :city_name")->setParameter("city_name",$cityName)
    ->innerJoin("sp.offers","offer")
    ->innerJoin("offer.service","service","with","offer.service = service")
    ->orderBy("sp.points", "DESC")
    ->addOrderBy("sp.name", "ASC")
    ->addOrderBy("service.points");
```

[See the documentation on this topic.](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#order-by-clause)

Comment: adding the order by can work like this  ->orderBy("sp.points DESC , sp.name ASC , service.points")
its in the documentations and this is not working applying even if i split it into addOrderBy because this will end up with one ServiceProvider and also it wont order the offers related to service's points :/

Comment: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/ordered-associations.html

Comment: @YamenImadNassif In the case of the querybuilder you can only add one ordering with orderBy, and additional orderings with addOrderBy. Your link is using DQL, not querybuilder. See: https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/QueryBuilder.php#L1259

Comment: yeah but both cases won't get me what i need

Comment: I didn't get. @SolarBear is right, except `->innerJoin("offer.service","service","with","offer.service = service")` should be only `->innerJoin("offer.service","service")`. What is going wrong?

Comment: what's going wrong that when i apply the above code with or without "with" and with or without "addOrder" it will end up with only having one ServiceProvider result and offers are not ordered

Answer (score 0):

The @SolarBear 's answer is almost correct.

```
$query->select("sp, offer, service")
   ->from("CoreBundle:ServiceProvider","sp")
   ->andWhere("sp.city = :city_name")->setParameter("city_name",$cityName)
   ->innerJoin("sp.offers","offer")
   ->innerJoin("offer.service","service")
   ->orderBy("sp.points", "DESC")
   ->addOrderBy("sp.name", "ASC")
   ->addOrderBy("service.points","DESC");
```

Notice, I remove the unnecessary code in the service Inner Join. And more important, add 'DESC' string in `service.points` order by. It should do the trick.

Let's jump to your example :

First of all, I honestly didn't understand you map in column `ServiceProvider.offers`.  Second, I change names of these table to be more clear to show the expected result.

ServiceProvider

```
-------------------------------------------------
id      |        name     |    points    |offers|
-------------------------------------------------  
1       |        C        |      2       |1,2,3 |
-------------------------------------------------
2       |        B        |      1       |1,2   |
-------------------------------------------------
3       |        A        |      0       |1,3   |
-------------------------------------------------
```

ServiceOffer

```
-----------------------------------
id      |     name        |service|
-----------------------------------
1       |      Z          |   1   |
-----------------------------------
2       |      Y          |   1   |
-----------------------------------
3       |      X          |   2   |
-----------------------------------
```

Service

```
-----------------------------------
id      |    name    |    points  |
-----------------------------------
1       |      J     |      23    |
-----------------------------------
2       |      K     |      88    |
-----------------------------------
```

results

```
ServiceProvider.name | offers.name          |       
---------------------------------------------
       C             |   X, Y, Z or X, Z, Y |  <---- I explain below
---------------------------------------------       
       B             |   Y, Z or Z, Y       |  <---- Same
---------------------------------------------
       A             |   X, Z               |
---------------------------------------------
```

In this example, SeviceOffer `X` uses Service `K` (`points 88`). While, ServiceOffer `Y` and `Z` use Service `J` (`points 23`) so there is a draw between the ServiceProvider `Y` and `Z`, so the DB can returns they in any order.

**Edit**

About "offers" column. Notice you mapped as a One to Many relationship. But notice, in the given table example is sound like a Many to Many. Once, `ServiceProvider` has many `ServiceOffer` and vice-versa. So for this works properly you should create a join table and removing offers column. 
And map in ServiceProvider a [`ManyToMany` relationship](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-unidirectional).
Such as:

Providers_Offers

```
------------------------------
provider_id   |   offer_id   |
------------------------------
      1       |       1      |
------------------------------
      1       |       2      |
------------------------------
      1       |       3      |
------------------------------
      2       |       1      |
------------------------------
      2       |       2      |
------------------------------
      3       |       1      |
------------------------------
      3       |       3      |
```

Comment: i really appreciate your effort but for some reason when i add order by service.points first of all i only get one service provider and even then the offers are not ordered by the service points :/

i tried all of what you and @Solar Bear mentioned non of them seems to be working 

tried couple of more stuff not working as well 
i guess there is something wrong with the db model or something 

and actually splitting with addOrderBy is giving the same results when i use it with one orderBy 

i will try it later tonight on another db if it worked i will accept the answer

Comment: " I honestly didn't understand you map in collumn" i guess here is the problem with the mapping or something 
as i mentioned its a bit big DB and Entities to show it all but i will let you know as far as i find a solution for this

Comment: I guess the issue is there, in "offers" column.

Comment: It almost sounds like you're using a group by (to be returning only one entity), odd. It's worth noting that unless you specifically select the entities by alias ordering in query will probably not work as the sub entities will be lazy loaded outside of your original query. So you could also try altering the above select as such: $query->select("sp, offer, service")